# how do crypto implementations prevent reading out memory address of saved private key, while using it?

Tags: memory-management, cryptography

my questions is about general crypto implementations, specifically how they prevent reading the private key out from the memory.

i know e.g. in ssh, the private key is saved on the HDD, with permissions only for the user. But when the ssh process (or any other crypto implementation, regardless if asymmetric of symmetric) needs to decrypt sth, they obviously have to read the private key(if they use one) - how do such implementations prevent that other processes can read out the memory address for the private key variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without encapsulating encryption hardware the key will be available.

iOS gets around this when decryption binaries to run by using hardware decryption in the DMA (hardware path) between flash storage and RAM.

Serious security such as iMessages cloud store/forward and banking to name a couple use HSMs (Hardware Encryption Modules). The keys are never outside the hardware unless encrypted by an HSM key. The encryption is done in the HSM. But that is not enough in some situations the HSM must be in a secure area with sign-in. Further they are tamper resistant, they clear their keys if they sense a physical or access attack. To administer two keys are needed for the HSM and three or more administrators must be present each inserting their Smart Card (which in the case of iMessages is shredded after initial setup) and entering the associated code.

OK, but the real question is how much security do you need? Carefully evaluate who your potential attacker are, how much time, money and technical talent they have and how much they are willing to spend on your data. Evaluate the value of your data to you, your users, attackers and reputation.

If you protecting against the device's authorized user(s) there is little you can do, what you need is DRM.

If you are protecting agains a well-funded or repressive government there is little chance.

But if you do it right, control the software and hardware, you can come very close until the court order is issued (see FBI vs Apple).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do programming lanuage implementations (e.g. python on a "desktop" windows/unix system) use a similar hardware module?

Comment: The key point is hardware where the encryption key is never available outside the hardware. Some systems have a [TPM (Trusted Platform Module)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) but access may not be available to user programs. HSM prices start around $5,000 but there are some cloud based solutions.